Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set') at Object.<anonymous>
this is my code and idk why its not working, its for discord.js
// Load command files
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

idk what to try I searched everything but I don't see the issue i get this message in my terminal:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
    at Object.<anonymous>


The error is telling you that client.commands is undefined. So where does client come from in your code? Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]

Class "client" is missing a public property "commands". This property needs to be defined as a new map(key, value)
Here's how to solve it.
client.commands = new Discord.Collection(); // or new Map()

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

